# How to make dotnet api entrypoint landing directly to swagger docs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have this configuration for dotnet swagger gen:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "Demo",
            Version = "v1",
            Description = "This is a demo api"
        });

        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });
```

Is there any way to config so that when user goes to localhost:port/ lands directly to swagger docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to change config for the swagger UI:

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    options.RoutePrefix = "";
});
```