# ASP.NET Core 7 Minimal API - Swagger doesn't start

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, .net-7.0, minimal-apis

We have a minimal API application, and whenever we start the app, we get a "Localhost not found" error instead of getting the Swagger interface. If we add the /swagger to the end of the URL, Swagger comes up fine. Are we missing something when trying to get it to default to the Swagger interface?

Our `program.cs` looks like this:

```
using Dapr.Client;
using ErpInterfaceService.Abstractions;
using ErpInterfaceService.Data;
using ErpInterfaceService.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointDefinitions(typeof(Message));
builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// TODO: Move this connection string to a secrets store. 
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ErpInterfaceContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ErpInterface")));

builder.Services.AddSingleton(new DaprClientBuilder().Build());

var app = builder.Build();

// Apply any new migrations to the database
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ErpInterfaceContext>();
    dbContext.Database.Migrate();
}

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseEndpointDefinitions();
app.MapHealthChecks("/health");

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are we missing something when trying to get it to default to the Swagger interface?

No, [by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio):

> The Swagger UI can be found at `https://localhost:<port>/swagger`.

It seems that your app does not have the root url handler, i.e. something like:

```cs
app.MapGet("/", () => "ok");
```

The opening browser opening action/url opened in the development environment is usually controlled by [launchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson) file. Open it (usually is placed in `Properties` folder), locate the launched profile and add/change `launchUrl` property:

```json
{
  // ... 
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger", // <---- here
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5166",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    // ...
  }
}
```

Another option is to change the swagger url to the root one - check out this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76044500/2501279).